# Sound in pdf generated by beamer

Tags: beamer, pdf, audio

I am trying to include sound in beamer slides in such a way that the resulting pdf file works "independently" of any sound file (self-sufficient way). I found that with media9 it was possible to do so. I also found examples with movies that I wasn’t able to adapt for sound. Does anyone have a simple example (code) for sound?

Comment: For a while I thought what `self-sufficient.wav` might be.

Comment: There are sound examples with embedded (self-sufficient) and remote (downloaded during viewing time) MP3 files on p. 25 of the `media9` manual.

Comment: geneted = generated????

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.